# Executing grep with execvp, to read from pipe

Tags: c, grep, exec, pipe, execvp

I'm trying to imitate the function of the shell command line:

```
printenv |grep VISUAL
```

by creating a child process, executing `grep` in it, and from the parent function writing the environment variables to a pipe connected to `grep`. This doesn't work though; the `grep` function keeps printing everything I write to it(whatever string I `grep` for). This is the code (I removed the checking and handling of error codes):

```
#define PIPE_READ 0
#define PIPE_WRITE 1
pid_t pid;


int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
   int pipe_fd[2];
   int return_value, status;
       return_value=pipe(pipe_fd);
       pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        dup2(pipe_fd[PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO); /*Grep should read from pipe*/
        close(pipe_fd[PIPE_READ]);
        close(pipe_fd[PIPE_WRITE]);
        char *arg_list[] = {"grep", "VISUAL",NULL};
        execvp("grep", arg_list); /*here somewhere is where I think the problem 
  lies, although I've tried everything here. The first argument is the command to
  execute, the second is the name of it again, the thirt should be the string to 
  search for and a file is optional, if there's no file it should read from 
  stdin (the pipe).*/
     }

     else /*parent process*/
     {
         close(pipe_fd[PIPE_READ]);
         int i;
                     /*Write the environment variables to the pipe.*/
         for(i=0; envp[i]!=NULL; i++)
         {
            write(pipe_fd[PIPE_WRITE],envp[i], strlen(envp[i]));
         }
         close(pipe_fd[PIPE_READ]);


     }
}
```

Comment: Always ensure that your program at least handles the error if `execvp()` fails (returns). If it succeeds, it does not return. At least add `exit(1);` or `_exit(1);` but I normally print an error message to standard error too.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you are closing `pipe_fd[PIPE_READ]` twice in the parent process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Like I said I removed the handling of errors to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Arkku Thanks! The seccond one is supposed to be closing the write side.

Comment: unrelated: you should really add the error handling. Here's an [example how pipe/fork/dup2/execve errors can be handled](https://gist.github.com/zed/7418439#file-sort-parallel-uniq-c). Especially the `write()` call, otherwise you can miss some output silently.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Maybe I was unclear, I do have error handling, but I removed it from this post to make it easier for people to read.

Comment: @Rickard: my mistake. I've missed it. I see, you wrote: *"I removed the checking and handling of error codes"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you do not write linefeeds to the pipe, which means that if anything in the whole string you write matches, `grep` will output the whole string since it is only one line. Try adding a second write after the first:

```
write(pipe_fd[PIPE_WRITE],"\n",1);
```

Comment: +1: Correct diagnosis. I guess the second `write` call is easy; it is tempting to suggest [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html): `dprintf(pipe_fd[PIPE_WRITE], "%s\n", envp[i]);` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I had that in mind, so I tried adding a "\n" to every string I wrote, but I guess I failed with that somehow.